# How to automatically kill long running MySQL queries after N seconds in mysql?

Tags: mysql

Is there any configuration setting using which long running query can be killed automatically in mysql?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46154701/automatically-kill-long-running-queries-mysql-apache-tomcat-datasource

Answer (score 4):

yes you can ! There is two ways of doing it.

**In query**

It sets a timeout in milliseconds.

```
SELECT /*+ MAX_EXECUTION_TIME(1000) */ status, count(*) FROM articles GROUP BY status ORDER BY status;
```

**With server variables**

```
SET SESSION MAX_EXECUTION_TIME=2000;
SET GLOBAL MAX_EXECUTION_TIME=2000;
```

These set a *session-wide and global timeout*.

I took the answer from [this website](https://tideways.com/profiler/blog/use-timeouts-to-prevent-long-running-select-queries-from-taking-down-your-mysql).

I hope it helped.